# How to get a press event on a parent layout?

Tags: android

I'm working on Android 2.2.3. I have a Button inside a FrameLayout, so that the button covers the entire FrameLayout.

When i press the button only the button's selector gets the event of pressing. 
The frame's selector dose not get this event since the button is on top of it. 
i.e: the attribute "android:state_pressed="true" happens for the button and not for the frame.

i need the press event and not the click event.

I would like to make the frame's selector to be set to android:state_pressed="true" when the button is pressed.

I've tried using

```
mMuteBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                mFrameMute.setPressed(true);
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                mFrameMute.setPressed(false);
            }
            return false;   
        }
    });
```

but ***it blocked the onClick() event*** which I also need for some other work.

**My main.xml file is:**

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_mute1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_background" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mute_btn1"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/selector_button"

        android:text="mute"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**The selector_background:**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg3" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bg1"/>
```

**The selector_button:**

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image1"/>
```

Comment: At a time only one view can handle the touch or click event in your current layout ..however your can have more weigth of framelayout to make it touch enabled... and what you want to do with frame layout touch state if you let me know then might me i can give to another solution ..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can start by returning `true` in the `onTouch` method in order to keep receiving touch events.

Did you try to set the FrameLayout to clickable and/or focusable? Maybe it helps:

```
mFrameMute.setClickable(true);
mFrameMute.setFocusable(true);
```

If you don't manage to get it working an ugly but not-so-bad approach would be to change the background of the `FrameLayout` programmatically.